# Payex intergration with PHP

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment

I have to integrate payex account e payment gateway in my application, I have searched for more than a week but i couldnt find good examples explaining the flow.. pls suggest me some good tutorials to understand Payex

Comment: dear @Radu please read the question twice before commenting..  i asked for payex client account e-payment and you were given credit card processing using payex. i already noticed this page with in a second after starting my search. i humble request please don't under estimate any body

Comment: Can you outline here what you've tried? Whilst you may have done thorough and valuable research already, it is a good idea to evidence it `:)`.

Answer (score 1):

They have documentation and help [here](http://pim.payex.com/) but you need a login and password to access it. Your client should be able to give that to you.

Comment: Thanks @john Conde,  i think you are saying about the site http://www.payexpim.com/ with the username and password ? if so.. i have tried this also. sory to say this I was unable to grasp the work flow as i was new to soap and payment gateway integration. please help me

Comment: @PackiyaRajan - it's really not a good idea to give security credentials on a website like this. I recommend you delete that comment and re-add it without confidential info.

Comment: @halfer, I am so sorry i have made relevant changes in that  comment, and those are not security credentials.. it is a common user name and password for test users that's why i did that mistake and i'll rectify it

Comment: @PackiyaRajan you should ask a new question here showing the code you've tried and where you are stuck. That way our SOAP experts can give you a hand.

Comment: @JohnConde I have tried nothing , i gone through some tutorials. i dont know where to start , how the form to be structured , those tutorials are explaining me about the functions by payex and how to handle it..